# How to use a DEX aggregator in a fund without risking concurrency calls?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, 0x, decentralized-exchange, concurrency

I will begin with some context.

I currently building a kind of vault (like enzyme.finance or nested.fi) where an administrator can create a vault and then an investor can deposit fund in the form of a denomination token (like USDC).
Then the administrator can perform different action on it, like swap. So there is other tokens in the fund.
But at one moment in time an investor can decide to withdraw his shares in the fund in the form of the denomination asset.
Since his tokens have been swapped, its necessary to swap back a percentage of the fund's tokens to the denomination token.
But since I need to perform the swap to call the 0x API and then send the swap data to the contract if an other investor or the administrator change the content of the fund (ie the percentage of each tokens) then the swap data are no longer valid.

=> Hence my question, how is it possible to perform a swap with 0x (or another DEX aggregator like Paraswap or 1inch) without the risk of concurrency calls ?

(My first thought was to do it on-chain only but I didn't find a way to do it since it seems that the call to the API is mandatory.)

Comment: I think you should ask this directly from Enzyme.finance devs. Usually these kind of things are handled with some kind of a withdrawal delay.

Comment: thanks @MikkoOhtamaa!
I ask yesterday but no response for now.


Can you tell me more about your idea with the withdrawal delay ?